# If statement not working for marital status

Tags: c, if-statement

I am creating a program which requires user to enter their marital status.
i want to be able to ask them Yes or No and then use `if` statements .
my code just skips the `if` block and prints the `else` block.

```
#include<stdio.h>


int main(void)
{
int age;
char marr;

printf("Please enter your age: \n");
scanf_s("%d",&age);

getchar();// getchar() is being used to clear any buffer of any remaining      keystrokes that might stll be stored.
printf("Are you married ? (y/n)\n");
scanf_s("%c", &marr);
if (marr == 'y')
    printf("Married\n");
else
    printf("Unmarried\n");



}
```

for some reason, whatever I input, i still get the output as `unmarried`,
no idea why.

Comment: Check for the return of `scanf` and then print out the character that you received.

Comment: can you elaborate ? i don't get you sorry

Comment: Hm, I don't see what there is to elaborate. Never use an IO function like `scanf` without checking its return value. Only proceed if there is no error. In addition your function is supposed to have written a value into your variable `marr`. Look if the contents of that variable is as you expect.

Answer (score 0):

Use `scanf()` instead of `scanf_s()` in this case or you'll need a buffer size argument if your input parameter is a character. Too you can place a space before `%c` in the `scanf()`-statement instead of your `getchar()`-command.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main(void) {

    int age;
    char marr;

    printf("Please enter your age: \n");
    scanf("%d",&age);

    printf("Are you married ? (y/n)\n");
    scanf(" %c", &marr);
    if (marr == 'y')
        printf("Married\n");
    else
        printf("Unmarried\n");

}
```